# python mongodb find method not working

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, arguments

Here is my method:

```
def mongo_find(collection_name, find_value):    
    list(MongoClient("localhost:27017").db[collection_name].find(find_value))


find_value = {'milestones.content': {'$regex': 'The idea'}}, {'milestones.content'}

print(list(mongo_find(collection_name, find_value)))
```

I'm getting this error:

`TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping`

but following works okay:

```
list(MongoClient("localhost:27017").db[collection_name].find({'milestones.content': {'$regex': 'The idea'}}, {'milestones.content'}))
```

So when running `mongo_find` method I tried printing:

```
print(find_value)
({'milestones.content': {'$regex': 'The idea'}}, {'milestones.content'})
```

Probably because round brackets are added on both ends. Is there a solution?

Comment: Im not a python guy. shouldnt be the project {'milestones.content':1}

Comment: Hi!! Yes, it will be sorted in ascending order. In the way I do it will print out without alignment. thanks

Comment: Why there is no pattern in $regex I see only plain text.

Comment: In the above code what does "db" stand for . Could you try  list(MongoClient("localhost:27017")[<databasename>].collection_name.find({'milestones.content': {'$regex': 'The idea'}}, {'milestones.content'}))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your working example

```
list(MongoClient("localhost:27017").db[collection_name].find({'milestones.content': {'$regex': 'The idea'}}, {'milestones.content'}))
```

you are actually passing **two** parameters to the find function. The first one is of type [dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) and specifiies a filter

```
{'milestones.content': {'$regex': 'The idea'}}
```

while the second one is a python [set](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sets.htm) which will be used for the projection

```
{'milestones.content'}
```

You non-working version passes but **one** parameter to the `find()` method which is a python [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) (that is where the round brackets in your output come from) and looks like that:

```
({'milestones.content': {'$regex': 'The idea'}}, {'milestones.content'})
```

So to fix that you would want to pass two parameters like in your working example:

```
def mongo_find(collection_name, filter. projection):
    list(MongoClient("localhost:27017").db[collection_name].find(filter, projection))

filter = {'milestones.content': {'$regex': 'The idea'}}
projection = {'milestones.content'}

print(list(mongo_find(collection_name, filter, projection)))
```

Comment: Thank you to much